# How do you pause a python script on input at any moment while it's running?

Tags: python, input, pause

I'm using selenium to do some webdriver stuff and I'd like to pause / resume it at any time on input of the enter key while I'm running it in anaconda prompt.

I know you can use

```
input()
```

at a certain point to make it wait for you to input but I can't figure out how to make it so that anytime I input it pauses and then again input to resume.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can we make selenium webdriver to wait until user clicks on a webpage link at run-time without using implicit wait?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21036239/can-we-make-selenium-webdriver-to-wait-until-user-clicks-on-a-webpage-link-at-ru)

Comment: unfortunately not, this method is still at a prescribed point in time, vs at any point

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to achieve this via Python changes, I'd suggest doing it through whatever command prompt / terminal you're using the run the script.

On Linux or Mac systems, you can press `ctrl+Z` in the terminal while your program is running to make it pause. Then you could type `fg` when you want to resume.

Sounds like you're using Windows, which is too bad because I don't know such an easy fix. I did a bit of Googling and saw some people talking about using "Process Explorer" to suspend processes, e.g. [here](https://www.gog.com/forum/general/can_windows_do_this_suspendresume_process_on_linux/post3), so you could try looking there if you want.

Anyway, I'll still leave this answer up because it could directly solve the problem for a future searcher who's running Linux or Max, but it seems like you might need to wait for help from someone with more Windows experience than me. Good luck :/

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion.

'ctrl+Z' didn't pause it. 

I'm on Windows 10 running Anaconda prompt (naconda3)

Comment: I also tried Ctrl+Pause and Ctrl+C - both of those stop the process completely.

Comment: I edited my post. I found one maybe-lead but I'm not so sure about it because I don't use Windows myself. Best of luck finding a fix!